# Hide some parts of a <path> generated with a curve interpolation

Tags: d3.js

All:

I am trying to make a customized line generator like D3 line(), but with ability to customize line segments style when there is data missing(like using dash line)

one thing I did not know how to implement is its .interpolate() function. The math seems complicated, what I am trying to do is just use existing D3 line function to draw those continus segments and connect them with dash line, but I can not figure out how to generate interpolated line?

In the code example below, u can see the dash line is not exactly overlap the solid line:

```js
var data = [];

for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
    if( i>0 && (i%4==0) ){
        data.push(null);
    }else {
        data.push({x:i, y:Math.random(i)})
    }
}

var x = d3.scale.linear();
var y = d3.scale.linear();
x.domain([0, 19])
      .range([10, 390])
y.domain([0, 1])
      .range([10, 360]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 400);
var lg = svg.append("g")
            .classed("lineGroup", true);
var xg = svg.append("g")
    .classed("xaxis", true)
    .attr("transform", function(){
        return "translate(0, 380)";
    });
var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("monotone")
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
line.defined(function(d) { return d!=null; });

lg.append("path")
    .classed("shadowline", true)
    .attr("d", function(){
        return line(data.filter(function(d){return d!=null;}));
    })
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px")
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");
lg.append("path")
    .attr("d", function(){
        return line(data);
    })
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px");
lg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.filter(function(d){return d!=null;}))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .style("fill", "orange")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px")
    .attr("r",5)
    .attr("cx", function(d){return x(d.x);})
    .attr("cy", function(d){return y(d.y);})
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(x)
                  .orient("bottom");
xg.call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: can you set up an example..of whats your datapoints and how the line should look.When should it become dashed. Currently your question is very generic.

Comment: @Cyril THanks, I added a concrete example, what I want is make that solid line curve interpolated to overlap the dash line

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a weird algorithm to hide some parts of your line, first of all you have to realize that the interpolation algorithm you chose works by [analyzing the previous and next points of any `t` between the previous and next point](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/line.js#L218-L233), therefore even if you want to generate only segment of the path you **have to use the same interpolation algorithm** otherwise the first/last points won't have the required curve

With that in mind my algorithm to solve your problem is as follows

- render the solid path
- render some segments of this solid path but with a white stroke so that it works like a mask
- render the dashed path

Implementation

- first render the solid path with the desired interpolation
- in the data find the extremes of all the gaps e.g. `gaps([0, 1, null, 3, 4, null, 5])` is transformed to `[[1, 3], [4, 5]]`
- compute the length of the path at those points, this involves an exhaustive brute force check since there's no api to get the length from the origin of a path to a determined point that lies on it, since your data is increasing on x I did binary search but for the general case as I've said you need to do a brute force check
- make a lot of samples between the gap endpoints (seen as path lengths) with `path. getPointAtLength` and finally render a path for each collection of points, the trick is to set a white stroke
- render the dashed path

NOTE: I changed the interpolation function to 'cardinal' so that curves are a lot more noticed and you can see the masks in action

```js
var data = [];

for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
    if( i>0 && (i%4==0) ){
        data.push(null);
    }else {
        data.push({x:i, y:Math.random(i)})
    }
}

var x = d3.scale.linear();
var y = d3.scale.linear();
x.domain([0, 19])
      .range([10, 390])
y.domain([0, 1])
      .range([10, 360]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 400);
var lg = svg.append("g")
            .classed("lineGroup", true);
var xg = svg.append("g")
    .classed("xaxis", true)
    .attr("transform", function(){
        return "translate(0, 380)";
    });
var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("cardinal")
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

function lineFiltered(data) {
  return line(data.filter(function (d) { return !!d }))
}

var basePath = lg.append("path")
    .attr("d", function () { return lineFiltered(data) })
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px");

function getPathLengthAtPoint(path, point, samples) {
  // binary search to find the length of a path closest to point
  samples = samples || 100
  var lo = 0, hi = path.getTotalLength()
  var res = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < samples; i += 1) {
    var mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2
    var pMid = path.getPointAtLength(mid)
    if (pMid.x < x(point.x)) {
      res = lo = mid
    } else {
      hi = mid
    }
  }
  return res
}

// gets endpoints from where there's a gap
// it assumes that a gap has only length 1
function getGapsEndPoints(data) {
  var j = 0
  var gaps = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    if (typeof data[i] !== 'number') {
      gaps.push([data[i - 1], data[i + 1]])
    }
  }
  return gaps
}

// generates multiple points per path
function generatePaths(data, path, samples) {
  samples = samples || 50
  return data.map(function (d) {
    var lo = d[0], hi = d[1]
    var points = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= samples; i += 1) {
      var point = path.getPointAtLength(lo + i/samples * (hi - lo))
      points.push({
        x: x.invert(point.x),
        y: y.invert(point.y)
      })
    }
    return points
  })
}


var missingData = data.map(function (d) {
  return d && getPathLengthAtPoint(basePath.node(), d)
})
missingData = getGapsEndPoints(missingData)
missingData = generatePaths(missingData, basePath.node())

// finally create the mask paths using the same line generator
lg.selectAll('path.mask').data(missingData)
  .enter().append('path').classed('mask', true)
  .attr('d', lineFiltered)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", "3px")

lg.append("path")
    .classed("shadowline", true)
    .attr("d", function () { return lineFiltered(data) })
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px")
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");

lg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.filter(function(d){return d!=null;}))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .style("fill", "orange")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px")
    .attr("r",5)
    .attr("cx", function(d){return x(d.x);})
    .attr("cy", function(d){return y(d.y);})
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(x)
                  .orient("bottom");
xg.call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

Imagine you have an array like this:

`[1,2,3, null, 4,5, null,null, 8,9]`

Break it into two array groups

`datachunks = [[1,2,3],[4,5][8,9]`

`brokenDataChunks = [[3,4][5,8]]`

Now draw the `datachunks` like this:

```
datachunks.forEach(function(dc){
  lg.append("path")
      .attr("d", function(){
          return line(dc);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke-width", "3px")
})
```

Now draw the `brokenDataChunks` like this:

```
brokendatachunks.forEach(function(dc){
  lg.append("path")
      .classed("shadowline", true)
      .attr("d", function(){
          return line(dc);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "red")
      .style("stroke-width", "3px")
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");
})
```

The main challenge was to get the array split into this fashion:

```
var datachunks = [];//hold data chunks for the blue line connected one
var brokendatachunks = [];//hold data chunks for the red dashed line disconnected ones
var tempconnected =[];
var tempbroken =[];
data.forEach(function(d, i){
  if(d){//if not null
    tempconnected.push(d); //push in tempconnected
    if (tempbroken.length > 0){
      tempbroken.push(d);//if broken was detected before
      brokendatachunks.push(tempbroken);//add this array into brokendatachunks.
      tempbroken = [];//set the new value in temp broken to get new set of values
    }
  } else {
    if(data[i-1])
      tempbroken.push(data[i-1]);//push previous value don't want to insert null here.
    datachunks.push(tempconnected);
    tempconnected = [];
  } 
});
if (tempconnected.length > 0){
  datachunks.push(tempconnected);
}

if (tempbroken.length > 0)
  brokendatachunks.push(tempbroken);
}
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/G8YXjhAKbXDpesbOzOm5?p=preview)

complex case with lot of broken points in between [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7sA1vaom1uXnO1afnP9A?p=preview)
In complex case I have put point generation like this

```
for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
    if( i>0 && (i%4==0 || i%3 ==0) ){
        data.push(null);
    }else {
        data.push({x:i, y:Math.random(i)})
    }
}
```